# Uploading multiple files to heroku serially locks up all dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

Its my understanding that when I upload a file to my heroku instance its a synchronous request and I will get a 200 back when the request is done, which means my upload has been processed and stored by paperclip.

I am using plupload which does a serial upload (one file at a time).  On Heroku I have 3 dynos and my app becomes unresponsive and I get timeouts trying to use the app.  My upload should really only tie up at most a single dyno while all the files are being uploaded since its done serially and file 2 doesnt start until a response is returned from file 1.

As a test I bumped my dynos to 15 and ran the upload. Again I see the posts come into the logs and then I start seeing output of paperclip commands (cant remember if it was identify or convert) and I start getting timeouts.

I'm really lost as to why this is happening.  I do know I 'can' upload directly to s3 but my current approach should be just fine.  Its an admin interface that is only used by a single person and again at most it should tie up a single dyno since all the uploaded files are sent serially.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into delayed_paperclip(https://github.com/jstorimer/delayed_paperclip).  If you have paperclip creating styles for the uploaded images it can be resource intensive as image processing can be a bottleneck.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at the gem.. but is there a gap in my understanding?  Even if it is process intensive, its still serial.

Comment: delayed_paperclip + workless gems. delayed_paperclip spawns Delayed_Jobs for each bit of file processing, and workless auto-spawns Heroku workers to crunch on them in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on the same problem for a couple of days. The problem, so far as I understand, is that when uploading files through heroku, your requests are still governed by the 30 second timeout limit. On top of this, it seems that subsequent requests issued to the same dyno (application instance) can cause it to accrue the response times and terminate. For example, if you issue two subsequent requests to your web app that each take 15 seconds to upload, you could recieve a timeout, which will force the dyno to terminate the request. This is most likely why you are receiving timeout errors. If this continues on multiple dynos, you could end up with an application crash, or just generally poor performance.

What I ended up doing was using [jquery-file-upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). However, if you are uploading large files (multiple MBs), then you will still experience errors as heroku is still processing the uploads. In particular [I used this technique](http://pjambet.github.com/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/) to bypass heroku entirely and upload directly from the client's browser to s3. I use this to upload to a temp directory, and then use carrierwave to 're-download' the file and process medium and thumbnail versions in the background by pushing the job to Qu. Now, there are no timeouts, but the user has to wait for the jobs to get processed in the background.

Also important to note is that heroku dynos operate independently of each other, so by increasing the number of web dynos, you are creating more instances of your application for other users, but each one is still subject to 30 second timeouts and 512Mb of memory. Regardless of how many dynos you have, you will still have the same issues. [More dynos != better performance](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#understanding-concurrency).

Comment: But in my case the upload is serial.  Upload 2 does not even begin until upload 1 has received a 200 response.  In that situation, I should never have two uploads occurring at once.  What seems to happen is heroku issues thh 200 response ..meanwhile paperclip has issued an exec on the kernel for convert/identify which is outside the request but causes your dynos resources to dry up... thats my theory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Dropzonejs in order to divide your files in queue and send them separately. That way the request wont timeout.